# remove images with the use of button

Tags: javascript

Supposed I have a function that pushes the image files on array and preview it

```
previewImages: function()
{
    let iFileLength = this.files.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        oHome.aFiles.push(this.files[i]);
    }

    function readAndPreview(file) {
        if (!/\.(jpeg|png|gif|jpg)$/i.test(file.name)) {
            return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
            let image = new Image();
            image.classList.add('mr-2', 'mt-2', 'w-100', 'h-100');
            image.title  = file.name;
            image.src    = this.result;

            let oButton = document.createElement("button"); //Button for the remove of image
            oButton.classList.add('close');
            oButton.type = "button";
            oButton.innerHTML= "x";

            let oDiv = document.createElement("div");
            oDiv.classList.add('col-md-3', 'mt-2');
            oDiv.appendChild(oButton);
            oDiv.appendChild(image);

            oHome.oImgPrev.appendChild(oDiv);
        });

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
},
```

After selecting the image the html will look now like this

[image]

Now that button X purpose is designed to remove the image on the array and remove also the element on the html.

Any idea how can I do this?  How can I know that the button is for that specific image.

Comment: *remove the image on the array* Do you mean the `oHome.aFiles` array?

Comment: Yes sir and remove the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a listener to the button that calls `.removeChild()` with the `oDiv`, and uses `findIndex` on the `aFiles` array to find the index of the file, so that it can be spliced out:

```
let oButton = document.createElement("button"); //Button for the remove of image
oButton.classList.add('close');
oButton.type = "button";
oButton.innerHTML= "x";
oButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  oHome.oImgPrev.removeChild(oDiv);
  oHome.aFiles.splice(oHome.aFiles.indexOf(file), 1);
});
```

Unless you *need* an array and its indicies, a Set might be easier to work with, since you can just `.add` and `.delete` items from it, without worrying about indicies:

```
oHome.aFiles = new Set();

// To add:
oHome.aFiles.add(this.files[i]);

// To remove:
oHome.aFiles.delete(file);
```

Comment: sir you mean oHome.aFiles.splice?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add a `click` event listener that removes the `file` element at the current `index`, from the `files` array as shown in the updated `readAnPreview()` below:

```
    let iFileLength = this.files.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        /* Update this line */
        oHome.aFiles.push(this.files, i);
    }

    /* Update method signature */
    function readAndPreview(files, index) {

        const file = files[index];

        if (!/\.(jpeg|png|gif|jpg)$/i.test(file.name)) {
            return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
            let image = new Image();
            image.classList.add('mr-2', 'mt-2', 'w-100', 'h-100');
            image.title  = file.name;
            image.src    = this.result;

            let oDiv = document.createElement("div");
            oDiv.classList.add('col-md-3', 'mt-2');
            oDiv.appendChild(oButton);
            oDiv.appendChild(image);

            let oButton = document.createElement("button"); 
            oButton.classList.add('close');
            oButton.type = "button";
            oButton.innerHTML= "x";

            /* Add "image remove" logic, run when oButton is clicked */
            oButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

             /* Prevent default behavior of button (if any) */
             e.preventDefault();

             /* Remove the img and x button */
             image.remove();
             oButton.remove();

             /* Remove file at current index from files array */
             files.splice(index, 1);
            });

            oHome.oImgPrev.appendChild(oDiv);
        });
    }
```